# Creating a new reverse proxy configuration in Nginx routes to a different config

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have been banging my head on the wall with this. Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.

I have handful of websites/services running on various different servers. I have a reverse proxy running on a server here at home to route different subdomains to their destinations elsewhere. I create a new conf, I indicate where my proxy_pass should be going to. My /etc/nginx/conf.d has the many different configs but to keep it simple, let's say I have these three:

```
a.conf
b.conf
c.conf
```

Let's say c.conf is the new one I've created/working on setting up. Here is it's contents:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name newsubdomain.root.net;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://222.222.222.222:4011;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      #upgrade to WebSocket protocol when requested
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
```

}

where http://222.222.222.222:4011 is my (obfuscated) destination.

When navigating to newsubdomain.root.net, I end up landing at the proxy_pass that was configured in a.conf. While trying to troubleshoot, I've renamed a.conf to a.conf.bak. Now when navigating to newsubdomain.root.net, I am landing at the proxy_pass that is defined in b.conf.

It has to be something simple that I am missing but I'm at a loss at this point. I've setup tons of new configs this way (20+ on this server) with no issue and nothing has changed since then (at least to my knowledge, I'm the only one who accesses this server.)

I've searched for a solution to this but my search terms are not rendering anything pertinent. I am happy to provide any logs/additional information needed.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can lend some advice.

Comment: Could you check if you have `default_server` option for `listen` directive on any of your virtual hosts?

Comment: `grep -r default_server /etc/nginx` only shows in sites-available but not enabled or anywhere else.

Comment: it was meaned if you have some kind of catchall, however show pls `nginx -tT`

Comment: Other than changing domain names and IPs for privacy, this is what I've got. https://pastebin.com/BHLTJjNz (Output was wayy to long for a comment)

Comment: @sammo22 besides the fact that your nginx config looks like a mess (sorry for that), I advice you just to inspect everything from scratch and create basic default nginx config with single virtual host, then to add virtual hosts one-by-one until you find your problem.

Comment: When it shows the other domains - has the browser's address bar changed at all? It may be jumping to an invalid domain name or jumping to `https`. You should test the server with `curl -I http://newsubdomain.example.net`